# Custom Enumerated Product Attribute Doesn't Get Indexed

Tags: product-attribute, indexer, magento-1.14

I want to create a product attribute where the values are enumerated string codes like "value_1", "value_2", "value_2" so that I can match them cleanly without having to rely on an ID or a user facing label, which are both subject to change.

I created a "select" type attribute via installer and used my own source class with a simple getAllOptions() method. It shows up when editing products. Saving the value takes. The value gets stored in catalog_product_entity_varchar as it should.

Here is an example version of the custom source class:

```
<?php
class My_Catalog_Model_Source_Billingfrequency extends 
    Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Monthly',
                    'value' => 'monthly',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Annually',
                    'value' => 'annually',
                ),
            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that Magento does not push this value to flat tables. I also ensured that used_in_product_listing was on and reindexed.

Does anyone know if it's possible, using Magento product attributes to create an enumerated attribute without having to use the standard Magento ID/label values like you would set in the admin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your custom source model

```
/**
 * Retrieve flat column definition
 *
 * @access public
 * @return array
 */
public function getFlatColums()
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    $column = array(
        'default'   => null,
        'extra'     => null
    );
    if (Mage::helper('core')->useDbCompatibleMode()) {
        $column['type']     = 'varchar';
        $column['is_null']  = true;
    } else {
        $column['type']     = Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT;
        $column['nullable'] = true;
        $column['comment']  = 'Billing frequency column';
    }
    return array($attributeCode => $column);
}

/**
 * Retrieve Select for update attribute value in flat table
 *
 * @access public
 * @param   int $store
 * @return  Varien_Db_Select|null
 */
public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
{
    return Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')
        ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store, false);
}
```